# Using Meteor, what is the proper way to make a JSON array reactive?

Tags: json, meteor, html-table

I am planning to use [Meteor-Excel](https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-excel) to load Excel sheets in a Meteor v1.3 app, and convert the sheet to JSON. What I would like to do is to tie the cell values to a grid of checkboxes. What is the best way to do that so that it is reactive? The UI result should be an html table of checkboxes.

Here is a sample Excel file converted to JSON using [Meteor-Excel](https://github.com/netanelgilad/meteor-excel):

```
var myExcel = {
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "Rows": "Row1",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "FALSE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row2",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "FALSE",
      "C3": "FALSE",
      "C4": "FALSE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row3",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row4",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "FALSE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row5",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row6",
      "C1": "FALSE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "FALSE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row7",
      "C1": "FALSE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row8",
      "C1": "FALSE",
      "C2": "FALSE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row9",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row10",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "TRUE",
      "C4": "TRUE"
    },
    {
      "Rows": "Row11",
      "C1": "TRUE",
      "C2": "TRUE",
      "C3": "FALSE",
      "C4": "FALSE"
    }
  ]
}
```

The templates could be something like this:

```
<template name="excel">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each rows}}
                {{> row}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<template name="row">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{C1}}></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{C2}}></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{C3}}></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{C4}}></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

With a helper that returns the rows:

```
Template.excel.helpers({
    'rows': function(){
        return myExcel.Sheet1;
    }
});
```

However, I am not sure what `checked` should be, and how each checkbox should be bound to the JSON in order to be reactive.

**UPDATE:**

In order to have my checkbox render correctly, here is what I used below.

**Templates:**

```
<template name="excel">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Col 1</th>
                <th>Col 2</th>
                <th>Col 3</th>
                <th>Col 4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each rowData in rows}}
                {{> row data=rowData idx=@index}}
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>

<template name="row">
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{checked "C1"}} data-rowIndex="{{idx}}" data-column="C1"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{checked "C2"}} data-rowIndex="{{idx}}" data-column="C2"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{checked "C3"}} data-rowIndex="{{idx}}" data-column="C3"></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" checked={{checked "C4"}} data-rowIndex="{{idx}}" data-column="C4"></td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

**Code:**

```
var myExcelDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

Template.excel.helpers({
    'rows': function() {
        myExcelDep.depend();
        return myExcel.Sheet1;
    }
});

Template.row.helpers({
    'checked': function(column) {
        return this.data[column] && this.data[column].toLowerCase() == "true" ? "checked" : false;
    }
});

Template.excel.events({
'change input[type="checkbox"]': function(event) {
  var x = event.target.checked;
  var col = $(event.target).attr("data-column");
  this.data[col] = x.toString();
  myExcelDep.changed();
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a [tracker dependency](http://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#tracker_dependency).

Declare a dependency in your template code:

```
var myExcelDep = new Tracker.dependency;

Template.excel.helpers({
    'rows': function(){
        myExcelDep.depend(); // this registers the dependency
        return myExcel.Sheet1;
    }
});
```

Then in your code that creates/modifies your JSON, update the dependency:

```
 ...
 myExcel.push(sheet2); // or any change operation
 myExcelDep.changed(); // this triggers invalidated functions to update
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Is that different from storing the JSON in session? I guess that would be a solution too, except that the JSON would have to be retrieved from the session, modified, and restored in the session for every change. Any suggestion on how to bind each checkbox to a value in the JSON objects?

Comment: For that you need a template event that toggles the current value of that object.

Comment: I have noticed the change to brought to my original post, changing `checked` for `C1`, `C2`, `C3` or `C4`. However, that won't work. All it does is generating html like `<input type="checkbox" true>`. I still have a bit of work to do but basically, I had to create my checkboxes like this `<input type="checkbox" {{checked "C1"}}>`, and write the proper checked helper to handle that. I still have a bit of work to do, but I will post the solution when I am done.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot the `checked=` which i just added.

Comment: I can't explain why, but `<input type="checkbox" checked={{C1}}>` renders `<input type="checkbox">`, and the checkboxes are all checked even when C1, C2, C3, or C4 is "FALSE"... probably because it is a non-empty string. The solution is to use a helper function. See the details in the UPDATE section of my original post. Thanks however for putting me on the right track with the tracker dependencies. By the way, even if you have the rights to do so, I don't think it is a good idea to modify the OP post to show him the solution. It is better to put that in your answer section.

Comment: Oh well. Why are you storing booleans as strings?

Comment: The JSON sample comes from the conversion of an Excel file into JSON, and boolean appears to be converted into strings. Maybe that's because Excel does not really have a boolean type.